# Set disclosure button on an Array of annotations

Tags: ios, nsarray, mkmapview, uisegmentedcontrol, mkannotation

I can't figure out how to set a disclosure button on 1 group of annotations.

The annotations are separated in 3 kinds of Arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *category1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *category2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *category3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I add the annotation objects in these arrays like this:

```
myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
location.latitude = 52.381285;
location.longitude = 4.888740;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"";
myAnn.subtitle = @"";
[category1 addObject:myAnn];
```

And put them in another array:

```
[self.locationArrays addObject:category1];
```

I use a segmented control to show the 3 groups on the map.
currentAnnotation is an integer to use the objectAtIndex.

```
-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender
{
    int newAnnotations = ((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (newAnnotations != self.currentAnnotation)
    {
        [self.myMapView removeAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:self.currentAnnotation]];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:newAnnotations]];
        self.currentAnnotation = newAnnotations;

        [self.myMapView showAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:newAnnotations] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**My question is:**
How do the objects, for example, in `catergory1` get a disclosure button? 
And how should I use it with the `viewForAnnotation` and `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method, because I already included all the annotation with a left blue car accessory.

---

**Update**

ViewForAnnotation method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{   
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
    if (!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] || annotation == myMapView.userLocation || annotation == locationManager)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        else
        {
            //Blauw Navigatie Auto...
            UIImageView *carView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Driving"]];
            UIButton *blueView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44+30)];
            blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:1];
            carView.frame = CGRectMake(11, 14, carView.image.size.width, carView.image.size.height);
            [blueView addSubview:carView];
            annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = blueView;
        }

        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotations class]])
        {
            Annotations *myRightAnn = (Annotations *)annotation;
            if (myRightAnn.category == 1)
            {
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            }
            else
            {
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
            }
        }
    }
    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: Add a category property to the Annotations class and set it when adding an annotation.  In the delegate methods, check this property and handle accordingly.

Comment: Yes Anna, I've done that by making Annotations+Disclosure.h/.m and setting `-(void)setDisclore;` in the .h en make in in the .m. I only wonder how I must set it on the stage on the viewController?

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not clear in my comment.  I didn't mean add a property in an "Objective-C Category".  I meant add a property named "category" to your Annotations class.  I used the word "category" because you have three arrays named "categoryX".  I'll explain the rest in an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Annotations` class (the one that seems to implement `MKAnnotation`), add a property named "category" (the name has *nothing* to do with "Objective-C Categories" -- it's just in reference to what you've called your three arrays: category1..3, use a different name if you like):

```
@interface Annotations : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int category;     //<-- add this property

@end
```

Set the annotation's `category` property to 1, 2, 3, or whatever when creating the annotation:

```
myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
location.latitude = 52.381285;
location.longitude = 4.888740;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"";
myAnn.subtitle = @"";
myAnn.category = 1;     //<-- set to 1 because adding to category1 array
[category1 addObject:myAnn];
```

Then in `viewForAnnotation`, check the annotation's `category` property and set the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` as needed (*below is just a rough idea of the code*):

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return;
    }

    static NSString *reuseId = @"ann";
    MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView dequeueReusable...
    if (av == nil) {
        av = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation...
        av.image = ...
        av.leftCalloutAccessoryView = ...
        av.canShowCallout = YES;
        //Set other properties here that will be
        //the same for ALL annotations...
    }
    else {
        av.annotation = annotation;
    }


    //Set rightCalloutAccessoryView based on annotation **AFTER**
    //the dequeue/alloc+init...

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotations class]]) {
        Annotations *myAnn = (Annotations *)annotation;
        if (myAnn.category == 1) {
            //set right view to button only for category 1...
            av.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }
        else {
            //no right view for any other categories...
            av.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
        }
    }

    return av;
}
```

In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, check the annotation's class, cast it to `Annotations` and check the `category` if necessary and handle it as needed:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotations class]]) {
        Annotations *myAnn = (Annotations *)view.annotation;

        if (control == view.leftCalloutAccessoryView) {
            //handle left control tap...
        }
        else
            if (control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView) {
                //handle right control tap...
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you _could_ just check in `viewForAnnotation` if the annotation was contained in array `category1` instead of adding a property to the Annotations class but I think that makes the code less flexible.  Then the delegate method has to know about data outside the method, or if you decide to put the annotations in one array but still want to differentiate them, etc.  With the property directly attached to the annotation object, where and how the annotation object is stored is irrelevant and not a worry in the delegate method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Anna. Now I understand why you do it this way! Only thing for now is that I now have all the categories with a rightAccessory. I've set the rightAccessory after the deque alloc init from `MKAnnotationView` like you said. See me update about the `viewForAnnotation`

Comment: The right accessory logic is incorrectly inside the `if (!annotationView)` which means it will _not_ execute if a view is dequeued. The structure should be: `if (!annotationView) { ... } else { annotationView.annotation = annotation; } if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotations class]]) { ... } return annotationView;`.

Comment: In the `if (!annotationView) { ... } else { annotationView.annotation = annotation; }` did  left blue car accessory in the `else` and the `rightDetailDisclosure` in the `if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotations class]])` statement.

Comment: Is that a question?  The `else` part where the view's `annotation` is updated is a place to update the properties of a _re-used_ view.  If you only set the left accessory there, it won't appear on views that are created from scratch.  If the left accessory should appear on _all_ annotations, it belongs in the block where the view is _created_ (alloc+init).